# Is '$M$ is a model of cardinality $\kappa$' a type definable property?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

I think that for any given theory $T$, the statement in the question should be true.

My attempt of proof:

Let us fix a theory $T$ and a cardinal $\kappa$, we introduce variables $\{ z_\alpha : \alpha<\kappa \}$. We would like to construct a type $p$ in this variables such that $(a_\alpha)_{\alpha<\kappa}$ satisfy $p$ if and only if $\{ a_\alpha : \alpha<\kappa \}$ is the universe of a model of $T$.

I first looked at sentences with only one quantifier. Let $\varphi(x)$ be q-f. If $T$ implies $\forall x \varphi(x)$, then we add to $p$ the formula $\varphi(z_\alpha)$ for every $\alpha$. But if we are in the case $\exists x \varphi(x)$ I don't really know how to proceed. I would like to add something equivalent to $\bigvee_{\alpha<\kappa} \varphi(z_\alpha)$.

Comment: I feel like a whole paragraph of context, if not more, is missing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am trying to prove that the relation $E(x,y)$ defined by there exists $\mathcal{M}\preccurlyeq \mathfrak{C}$ such that $x\equiv_{M}y$ is $0$-type definable. Using Löwenheim-Skolem is enought to check models of cardinality $\lvert T \rvert$.

Comment: I think "if $(a_\alpha)_{\alpha<\kappa}$ satisfy $p$ then [stuff]" should be " $(a_\alpha)_{\alpha<\kappa}$ satisfy $p$ iff [stuff]." Otherwise just fix some model of size $\kappa$ and code its elementary diagram into $p$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber That is true, I will change it.

Comment: Then this is impossible - consider the theory $T$ of an infinite set with a single named constant $c$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I would think about that counterexample. Thank you. Do you know how to prove the statement in my first comment? or where to look for hints?

Comment: @UserUser: do you wnat a type whose realisation enumerates an *elementary* submodel, or a type whose realisation enumerates *any* submodel?

Comment: @tomasz only elementary submodels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you ask for, literally, is impossible, as in the example given by Noah in the comments --- in a type $p(\bar x)$ in infinitely many variables, you cannot assert in a first order way that *any* one of the variables in $\bar x$ represents the constant $c$.

What is possible is finding a type $p((x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\lambda})$ over $\emptyset$ such that the elementary submodels (of cardinality $\leq \lambda$ or $=\lambda$) are exactly the sets enumerated by realisations of $p$ (usually non-uniquely and non-injectively!).

Note that I will assume $\lambda\geq \lvert T\vert$. I suspect this should not be hard to extend to small models of large theories, but there will likely be some technicalities involved that I would rather avoid.

For a given set $M$ to be an elementary submodel, it is sufficient (and necessary) to know that it satisfies the Tarski-Vaught test, i.e. that for any formula $\varphi(x,\bar y)$ and any tuple $\bar b\in M$ such that $\models\exists x\varphi(x,\bar b)$, there is an $a\in M$ such that $\models \varphi(a,\bar b)$.

You are given a tuple $I = (x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\lambda}$ of variables, where $\lambda$  is an infinite cardinal $\geq \lvert T\rvert$.

To ensure that the Tarski-Vaught test is satisfied, you want to have, for each formula $\varphi(x,\bar y)$ and each tuple $\bar y\subseteq I$, there is some variable $z=z_{\bar y, \varphi}\in X$, such that your type has the formula $\tilde\varphi(\bar y, z_{\bar y,\varphi})=(\exists x \varphi(x,\bar y))\rightarrow \varphi(z_{\bar y,\varphi}, \bar y)$.

Now, in order to ensure that this is satisfiable, you need to be careful with your choice of $z_{\bar y,\varphi}$. The easiest way to do this is to first enumerate all pairs $(\bar y, \varphi)$ as a $\lambda$-sequence $(\bar y_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha)_{\alpha<\lambda}$ (this is why I wanted to assume that $\lambda\geq \lvert T\rvert$ --- otherwise, there would be too many formulas). To ensure that there is never any clash, you should choose $z_\alpha= z_{\bar y_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha}$ in such a way that $z_\alpha\neq z_\beta$ for $\beta<\alpha$ *and* $z_\alpha\notin \bar y_\beta$ for any $\beta\leq \alpha$. This is standard book-keeping. Given this, you can recursively find a realisation of this type (in any model of $T$, in fact), and it is not hard to see that it enumerates a submodel (by the Tarski-Vaught test).

Now, every realisation of this type will enumerate an elementary submodel. However, it is not obvious (to me) that every elementary submodel of cardinality $\leq \lambda$ has an enumeration satisfying this type. In order to have that, you need to ensure that there are $\lambda$-many variables which are not $z_\alpha$ for any $\alpha$. This is, again, straightforward book-keeping. Then given any elementary submodel, you can enumerate the model by the "un-assigned" variables, and then extend the enumeration to all variables in accordance with the Tarski-Vaught test.

(In order to ensure that you do not get any models of *smaller* cardinality than $\lambda$, you should additionally inject a requirement that $\lambda$ many variables refer to different elements, but that is also quite straightforward.)